# Better to have one generic method with a parameter or multiple methods?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I currently have my main form calling methods in my ObjectManager class which goes and loads some specified data from the database in a different thread (Using Task.Factory.StartNew()) and then throws an event to let the main form know when it's done so the form can update it's controls.

At the moment I let the main form know with a single event that has a parameter passed to it with what has changed (Opportunity/quote/job etc.).

I was wondering if it would be better to create separate events for each type of change?

DataChanged EventArgs:

```
class DataChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public String ObjectName { get; private set; }

    public DataChangedEventArgs(String objectName)
    {
       ObjectName = objectName;
    }
}
```

My event handler function

```
 private void dataChanged(object sender, DataChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ObjectName)
        {
            case "OpportunityList": 
                //Update Opportunity List
                break;

            case "Opportunity":
                //Update single opportunity details
                break;

            case "QuoteList":
                //Update Quote List
                break;

            case "QuoteDetails":
                //Update single quote details
                break;

            case "JobDetails":
                //Update job details
                break;

            case "OpportunityLogs":
                //Do Stuff
                break;

            case "QuoteLogs":
                //Do Stuff
                break;

            case "JobLogs":
                //Do Stuff
                break;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Where the event is invoked:
There are multiple methods similar to this that load something different/save something and then call the same event with a different parameter.

```
class ObjectManager
{
    public List<Opportunity> _opportunities;

    public void loadOpportunityDetails(int _opportunityID)
    {
        int index = _opportunities.FindIndex(
                delegate(Opportunity opportunity)
                {
                    return opportunity.opportunityID == _opportunityID;
                });

        //Load details of the given opportunity

        DataChangedEvent(this, new DataChangedEventArgs("OpportunityDetails"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where this event is being invoked?

Comment: If the actions executed for each of them are not completely similar, I'd definitely prefer them to be in different methods. Even if those actions are very similar and having them in one method is reasonable, using an `Enum` would be better than string matching imo.

Comment: Added that code. There are also similar functions in that class that do something different and then invoke the same event but they do all load 'something'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would certainly modify the calls so you aren't passing magic strings about, that's unnecessarily brittle.

If you have a separate method for each event it will be easier to maintain, test, and debug.

Comment: Different events it is then